# Working with path folder from VS Code e Kaggle getting different results

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kaggle

I have a notebook developed on Visual Studio Code, and if I run a command I get a result different from Kaggle.

Code:

```
path = os.path.realpath('/kaggle/input/netflix-prize-data')
path
```

If I run the code above I got the result below:

```
'E:\\kaggle\\input\\netflix-prize-data'
```

[image: Working at Kaggle notebook]

Not working on VS Code

[image: Not working on VS Code]

That works on Kaggle but not on my Windows, because the real path is different, so if I run without the first "/", like this:

```
path = os.path.realpath('kaggle/input/netflix-prize-data')
path
```

If I run the code above I got the result below:

```
'E:\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Cursos\\Estudos\\Netflix\\kaggle\\input\\netflix-prize-data'
```

But I'd like to have only one notebook that works both environments, is there any solution that could work?

Answer (score 0):

Because the operating system of the `kaggle` depends on was not the windows, it's a Linux.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. So is there no way? Do I have to keep with two versions of notebook (one for each)?